# Override single UI in Swing Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Is there a way to override just a single UI component's L&F (not a single instance of it, but all instances) with a custom one? Basically I want to override the L&F defaults for it.

It looks like all of that gets setup in `BasicLookAndFeel#getDefaults`

I guess if I really needed to I could create a custom look and feel that extends the one I want to use and override it in the `initClassDefaults` method, but I would prefer to just be able to override whatever UI is currently being used.

I was thinking I could just do `UIManager.put(<ui_class_id>,<my-delegate-classname>)`

This doesn't seem to work for the example I'm working on, but that could be because I'm trying to set a component that's not part of the standard look and feel (the component adds itself on). I'm trying to figure out if this is even the right approach.

Comment: only my curiosity, please why, why to override [UIDefaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party component that installs its own ui delegates. I want to customize how it looks so I'm trying to override the default ui used for that 3rd party component.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the problem was that I forgot to implement `createUI` in my UI. Once I did that, I was able to just call `UIManager.put(<ui_class_id>,<my-delegate-classname>)` and it worked.

Comment: Right, but that's for installing on a single component

Comment: I think the delegate also has to be `public`; I know it can't be nested. Note spelling of `UIManager`.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. And yes, That was a type-o above (corrected).

Answer (score 1):

[From the Java Tutorials:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic)

> Changing the Look and Feel After Startup
>
> You can change the L&F with setLookAndFeel even after the program's
>   GUI is visible. To make existing components reflect the new L&F,
>   invoke the SwingUtilities updateComponentTreeUI method once per
>   top-level container. Then you might wish to resize each top-level
>   container to reflect the new sizes of its contained components. For
>   example:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

In other words: you can change the look and feel of a top-level container (I don't have tested if it is limited to top-level containers only or if this method can be applied to any container). Or, to answer your question even more precisely: I don't see there's method of styling a *single* component, but **there is a way for single components in (toplevel) containers**.

Comment: I do not need to set the whole look and feel, just the one component

Comment: Important statement now in bold.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to change a L&F for a component

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
WindowsFileChooserUI wui = new WindowsFileChooserUI(fc);
wui.installUI(fc);
```

You can find all existing component class UI From

```
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.(L&F).*;
```